# How to call class function from seperate class function through Threading module Python

Tags: python, class, python-multithreading

I'm coding my own [Asteroids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asteroids_(video_game)) minigame using pygame (which is extremely inefficient with multiple sprites so wanted to use threading.

How do I access a function from another class (asteroids class) through my main class (handler) class.

If my class system is backwards or doesn't work using Threading, please explain to me how I could make it more efficient or easy to code in

```
class Asteroids():
    def __init__(self):
    ....
    def Update(self):
    ....

class Handler():
    def __init__(self):
    ....
    def Update_All(self):
    x = threading.Thread(target = ##Asteroids.Update()
    x.start()
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an instance of Asteroids

```
astroid = Astroids()
# then you can use the function in your thread
x = threading.Thread(target = astroid.Update)
```

Comment: `target = astroid.Update` - without `()`!

Comment: @ zvone / eric Yang 
this worked, thanks. I was tripping up on the astroid.Update bit as i saw no code on ( https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/ ) that allowed for this and when i did try, i had used () as a function.